# Issue in removing object using Lodash _remove

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, lodash

I am having an Object:

```
ids = [ "-LIof_e0hPtXKtkc4Uh9", "-LIjBcGO7m7VQ-B3pfYt" ]
```

If I Iterate using `.map` function of `lodash`

```
_.map(ids, (userID, key) => {
     console.log('Lopping userId',userID);
})
```

it gives me value of each id.

Now when I am trying to remove it using `_remove` it is not working as expected.

```
_.remove(ids, (value, key, obj) => value == idToBeRemoved);
```

Still there is no difference in `ids` Object.

I am really new to angular4 and using lodash for the first time.
I just wanted to remove a value from `ids` object and get the remaining object.

Print of console.

[image]
I am using firebase and trying to delete data after retrieving it from firebase :

```
deleteTransactWith(transactWithKey,transactWithUser) {
    let currentUser = this._authService.getLoggedInUser();
    console.log(transactWithUser.groups)
    console.log(Object.keys(transactWithUser.groups).length)
    console.log('key To remove',transactWithKey)
    for (var key in transactWithUser.groups) {
      if (transactWithUser.groups.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        let group = this.firebase.object(`/url/${currentUser.$key}/${key}`);
        group.snapshotChanges().take(1).subscribe((groupData: any) => {
          groupData = groupData.payload.toJSON();
          //console.log('not removed',groupData.userIds)
          console.log('key',transactWithKey)
          _.remove(groupData.userIds, (value) => value == transactWithKey);
          //_.pull(groupData.userIds, transactWithKey);
          console.log('removed',groupData.userIds)
        });
      }
  }
```

Comment: What's your `map` function meant to be doing?

Comment: Nothing. I just wanted to check the key and values

Comment: "I am having an Object:" -- no you're not, you have an array

Comment: you are having an array of elements

Comment: I have attached the image of console

Comment: @GeorgeJempty ["Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: So I cant remove it like this way ?

Comment: It should work, make sure your variable `idToBeRemoved` has a value which exist in array

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/bqfw8x7o/)

Comment: I will try and let you know

Comment: Can we continue this discussion on chat ?

Comment: I updated my answer. Still not getting it.is something else affecting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [_filter](https://lodash.com/docs/#filter) instead

```
const ids = [ "-LIof_e0hPtXKtkc4Uh9", "-LIjBcGO7m7VQ-B3pfYt" ]
const idToBeRemoved = "-LIof_e0hPtXKtkc4Uh9"
const filteredIds = _.filter(ids, function(id) { return id !== idToBeRemoved})
console.log(filteredIds)
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I have added a code in my question. Please check to that last function where I am fetching data from firebase. Can you please provide your answer based on that

Comment: Thank you that worked. Can you please explain why _remove was not working not even _pull

Comment: On the road. I will later tonight

Comment: _.remove & _.pull are similar. They remove elements from the source array and return them.
_.remove takes a function for comparison; _.pull takes a list of values to compare

_.filter uses a function to match items and returns all but the matched items. Doesn't change source collection.

What to use depends on if you want to change the original array, if you want the matches, or all but the matches.

Comment: That means _.remove and _.pull will not change original array ?

Comment: They both change the original array. _filter does not change the original. Lodash docs always tell you what it does. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use lodash [_.pull](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#pull)

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const ids = [ "-LIof_e0hPtXKtkc4Uh9", "-LIjBcGO7m7VQ-B3pfYt" ]
const result = _.pull(ids, "-LIjBcGO7m7VQ-B3pfYt" )
console.log(filteredIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

First find the index of what you are removed item and next pull out from it by  _.pullAt(lodash)

```
    let getIndex= _.findIndex(this.images, function(o) { return o.name == img.name; });
    let removedImage = _.pullAt(this.images, getIndex) ;
```